# Correct Git replacement of entire file

Tags: git, diff

I've committed a file on git, which has several changes, but is not completely different from the old file.  Rather than pick out the changes, git has made one big delete; the whole file, and one big insertion; the new file.  This is an error, there are clearly large unchanged sections, e.g. the file starts with a number of "using" statements, none of which have changed.

This is annoying as it means I'll lose all the "blame" history.

Is there a way to make git redo the diff?  What could I have done to cause this?  I was merging from another branch when this happened.

Comment: Are you sure there are no whitespace changes or line ending changes in those lines? What does `git diff --ignore-space-change` say?

Comment: Definitely look for invisible character changes inside the file (or something like tabs converted to spaces.

Comment: Aha!  For some reason when merging some different line endings had ended up in the file.  Visual Studio spotted it and suggested I normalise...so I must have changed all the line endings.  I'd forgotten about that.

Comment: If you'd like to add as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not store diff, it just stores a version of the file tree for each commit. The diff created by `git show` are not what is stored in Git internal DB.

In your case, you can see that the file has been renamed if you use the `-M` option of `git diff`

```
   -M[<n>], --find-renames[=<n>]
       Detect renames. If n is specified, it is a threshold on the similarity index (i.e. amount of addition/deletions compared to the file’s size).
       For example, -M90% means git should consider a delete/add pair to be a rename if more than 90% of the file hasn’t changed.
```

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: My understanding is that this is only true to a point.  When commits are stored, they are originally stored as full snapshots.  However, git routinely runs compression algorithms and creates packfiles.  Once this happens, it is likely the historical commits will be stored as deltas whereas the lastest version of a snapshot will be stored intact.  If new commits are added they too will be added as full snapshots until the packfile routine runs again.

Comment: @JosephDeCarlo, yes, but I think rcomblen was talking about semantics, and from this standpoint Git only manipulates snapshots.

Comment: @kostix ahhh... good point.  When I read rcomblen's answer, it made me question how I thought I knew it worked, so I looked it up and reread the chapter in progit.  Once I verified that my memory was correct, I figured I would just post it for clarity sake.